# Why we declare webelement as Private after @FindBy in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

Why do we declare `webelement` as `Private` while creating Pageobjects after FindBy in `Selenium Webdriver`? what if we declare as `Public` instead of `Private`?
Can any one answer this question.

```
@FindBy(id = "uniqName_34_0")
private WebElement username;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Do you know the difference between `public` and `private` keywords? I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, should any class other than `HomePage` be able to work directly with it's `username` `WebElement`?

I would argue that you shouldn't have the `public` accessor method either, especially if you're using the `Page Object Pattern`.

Your test scripts shouldn't interact directly with `WebElements`, instead they interact with `PageObjects` that are responsible for knowing how to perform functions on it's page. So your `HomePage` might have a method that looks like this:

```
public HomePage enterUsername(string user)
{
    username.sendKeys(user);
    return this;
}
```

That way your test script doesn't care how to interact with the page, it's only worried about needing to enter a username. To protect yourself from using `WebElements` in your test script, don't expose them through public fields or accessor methods.

You might consider marking them `protected` as needed if you have some inheritance in your `PageObject` architecture, but other than that your `WebElement`s should be private to the page they belong to.